# Write multiple excel files for each unique ID in a data.frame

Tags: r, data.table

I want to write an Excel file for each unique ID with required date range.
The below is a snapshot of raw data in text.

```
ID,Type,PostCode,Date
15,SS,2520,2015-11-01
15,SS,2520,2015-10-01
20,SS,2520,2015-11-20
16,SS,2520,2015-11-12
16,SS,2520,2015-10-25
11,SS,2520,2015-10-14
20,SS,2520,2015-11-30
```

The data can have 100+ of individual ID with more than 100 thousand rows.
I want to read the raw data and write the separate excel file with the data table in required date range for each ID ideally with the file name of ID number.

My attempt

```
myfunction <- function(startdate, enddate) {
x <- read.table("aaa.text", sep = ",")
split(x,x$ID)
}
```

Any advice or suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Using `data.table` and `xlsx`, the following will do the trick:

```
library(data.table)
library(xlsx)
setDT(x)
x[ , write.xlsx(.SD, file = paste0(.BY[[1]], ".xlsx")), by = Date]
```

From there, it's bells and whistles.

You'll notice this prints a column of row names -- `write.xlsx` has an option to turn this off (`row.names = FALSE`).

If you want to include `Date` as a column in your output, it'll be a tiny bit more nebulous (props to Frank for cleaning it up):

```
x[ , write.xlsx(c(.BY, .SD), file = paste0(.BY[[1]], ".xlsx")), by = Date]
```

Basically, because `.SD` and `.BY` are both `list`s, `c` just concatenates, and apparently `write.xlsx` works fine on lists.

Comment: @Frank indeed it seems to. Also confirmed if `.N > 1` for any value of `Date`. Now the first two times I've ever used `.BY` in an answer o.O